# How do I show Data Validation red circles when sheet is protected?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, data-validation

I'd like to show all invalid data on my worksheet using Data -> Data Validation -> Circle Invalid Data, but this is disabled when the sheet is protected (i.e. Review -> Protect Sheet). Is there a setting or something I can change so I can display the red circles while the sheet is protected? I'm using data validation here to help customers make sure a document is fully filled out before submission. Thanks

Excel 2016, Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mechanism to enable circling of invalid data on a protected sheet is to create a macro that is activated from a button to programmatically invoke the function.  The code would look like this:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
  ActiveSheet.CircleInvalid
End Sub
```

A second button can give access to clear validation circles:

```vb
Sub Button2_Click()
  ActiveSheet.ClearCircles
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this solution requires you to use a macro-enabled spreadsheet.  If your company security practices make this impractical, then you are out of options.  Leaving the sheet unprotected enables the buttons.  But a paste of a value into a cell having a validation rule wipes out the validation rule so that your Circle Invalid Data will still not work because the paste action overwrites the rule that you were intending to enforce.